# CSS & Entypo font not playing nicely

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I've run out of options with this particular issue I'm having.

I'm using entypo font to display a few icons but their dimensions all seem out of whack and I can't seem to control or modify them enough to get the desired result.

All I want is:

Email Icon : Email me
email@email.com

I've tried normal inline elements, then I placed them in divs to try and force them and then I resorted to putting them in a table(exasperation) but still no joy.

Would someone mind have a look this this fiddle and seeing if they can see what the fix might be?

```
Links must be accompanied by code?
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KafdH/

Many thanks!

Apologis for some of the css, it may seem illogical, I was trying all sorts of wild wacky things.  It's almost as though the icon has a large invisible space above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the fiddle will save, but:  [http://jsfiddle.net/KafdH/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/KafdH/) seems to bring it up for me.  Your "h4" was forcing too much white space, I think.  I tried bold, instead, and the font looked the same.  I also had to put the entire line in the span, though I hope with more real estate that won't be necessary.

```
<span id="entypoFont" class="mail icon"> <b> Email me:</b>      
blah@bla.co.uk</span>
<span id="entypoFont" class="mail icon">
              <b> Email me:</b>
               yadda@bla.co.uk</span>
```

Comment: fantastic!Thanks!  could you edit the answer please to remove email address ? :)